# Images show in IE, but not in Firefox

Tags: css, xml

I am adding images as follows with XML and CSS:

```
<html:img src="./pictures/logo.jpg" alt="dupa"/>
```

They are showing correctly in IE, but not in Firefox. What could be the cause and how can I solve it?

I use this, but still can't see a picture...
My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="styl.css"?>
<dokument xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<logo><img src="./Obrazki/logo.jpg"/></logo>
</dokument>
```

Comment: i'm sorry. it was my mistake. I just wrote it wrong there.. But still have a problem

Comment: All I did was change what was there to be visible.  I suspected the "$" was an error, but not being sure of the intent, didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sollution was:

```
<dokument xmlns:html='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
```

instead of a

```
<dokument xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<img src="./pictures/logo.jpg" alt="dupa" />
```

read this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Comment: so, when I use this stll don't have a pic :> When I add "html" before "img", then my pic is visable on the site